# Write a Binary Sequence in ASCII to Binary python

Tags: python, binary, compression, ascii, huffman-code

I'm implementing Huffman Algorithm, but when I got the final compressed code, I've got a string similar to below:

```
10001111010010101010101
```

This is a binary code to created by the paths of my tree's leafs.

I have this sequence, but when I save it in a file, all that happens is system saving it as a ASCII on a file, which I can't compress because it has the same or bigger size than the original.

How do I save this binary directly?

PS: if I use some function to convert my string to binary, all I got is my ASCII converted to binary, so I did nothing, I need a real solution.

Comment: And how many *bytes* is this supposed to be written as? Big endian, little endian?

Comment: You could use the [Bitwise I/O](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitwise_IO#Python) recipe mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10691412/355230) answer of mine to another question about reading bits.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is take each 8 bits and convert it into a byte to write out, looping until you have less than 8 bits remaining. Then save whatever's left over to prepend in front of the next value.

```
def binarize(bitstring):
    wholebytes = len(bitstring) // 8
    chars = [chr(int(bitstring[i*8:i*8+8], 2)) for i in range(wholebytes)]
    remainder = bitstring[wholebytes*8:]
    return ''.join(chars), remainder
```

Comment: How to get back this value from the file, because your solution have worked, but I have no idea how to read it back.

Comment: @user3923894 that sounds like another question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `int()` with a base value of 2:

```
my_string = "10001111010010101010101"
code_num = int( my_string, 2 )
```

Then write to a binary file. struct.pack additionally allows you to specify whatever byte order you like.

```
myfile = open("filename.txt",'wb')
mybytes = struct.pack( 'i', code_num )
myfile.write(mybytes)
myfile.close()
```

This method will also write some number of leading zeros, which could cause trouble for your Huffman codes.

Comment: Huffman codes tend to be a variable number of bits, so you can't convert to a constant size integer.

Comment: Edited to allow larger ints