# Save list of numbers to (binary) file with defined bits per number

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion, byte, bit

I have a list/array of numbers, which I want to save to a binary file.
The crucial part is, that each number should not be saved as a pre-defined data type.
The *bits per value* are constant for all values in the list but do not correspond to the *typical* data types (e.g. byte or int).

```
import numpy as np

# create 10 random numbers in range 0-63
values = np.int32(np.round(np.random.random(10)*63));

# each value requires exactly 6 bits
# how to save this to a file?

# just for debug/information: bit string representation
bitstring = "".join(map(lambda x: str(bin(x)[2:]).zfill(6), values));
print(bitstring)
```

In the real project, there are more than a million values I want to store with a given bit dephts. 
I already tried the module bitstring, but appending each value to the BitArray costs a lot of time...

Comment: The `PackedIntArray` class in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29907689/355230) of mine might be useful (although it's implemented using `BitArray`). Regardless, there's a fair amount processing involved in doing what you want—especially for a long list of numbers—and there's no getting around it. `BitArray` is written in C, so should be close to as fast as you're going to get without writing your own custom C extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The may be some `numpy`-specific way that make things easier, but here's a pure Python (2.x) way to do it. It first converts the list of values into a single integer since Python supports `int` values of any length. Next it converts that `int` value into a string of bytes and writes it to the file.

Note: If you're sure all the values will fit within the bit-width specified, the `array_to_int()` function could be sped up slightly by changing the `(value & mask)` it's using to just `value`.

```
import random

def array_to_int(values, bitwidth):
    mask = 2**bitwidth - 1
    shift = bitwidth * (len(values)-1)
    integer = 0
    for value in values:
        integer |= (value & mask) << shift
        shift -= bitwidth
    return integer

# In Python 2.7 int and long don't have the "to_bytes" method found in Python 3.x,
# so here's one way to do the same thing.
def to_bytes(n, length):
    return ('%%0%dx' % (length << 1) % n).decode('hex')[-length:]

BITWIDTH = 6
#values = [random.randint(0, 2**BITWIDTH - 1) for _ in range(10)]
values = [0b000001 for _ in range(10)]  # create fixed pattern for debugging
values[9] = 0b011111  # make last one different so it can be spotted

# just for debug/information: bit string representation
bitstring = "".join(map(lambda x: bin(x)[2:].zfill(BITWIDTH), values));
print(bitstring)

bigint = array_to_int(values, BITWIDTH)
width = BITWIDTH * len(values)
print('{:0{width}b}'.format(bigint, width=width))  # show integer's value in binary

num_bytes = (width+8 - (width % 8)) // 8  # round to whole number of 8-bit bytes
with open('data.bin', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(to_bytes(bigint, num_bytes))
```

Comment: I did not know that python int values can have any length. Saving the whole array in a single int is a really clever way. Thank you :-)

Comment: Alexander: Yes, in Python `int`s are variable length, like strings, and that feature can sometimes be useful in totally unexpected ways. Think of it generally as a way to allow a bit sequence of any length to be treated as a single number or quantity—which will put you in a position to wield yet another of the language's many secret sauces. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you give an example with a string, I'll assume that's how you get the results. This means performance is probably never going to be great. If you can, try creating bytes directly instead of via a string.

Side note: I'm using Python 3 which might require you to make some changes for Python 2. I *think* this code should work directly in Python 2, but there are some changes around bytearrays and strings between 2 and 3, so make sure to check.

```
byt = bytearray(len(bitstring)//8 + 1)
for i, b in enumerate(bitstring):
    byt[i//8] += (b=='1') << i%8
```

and for getting the bits back:

```
bitret = ''
for b in byt:
    for i in range(8):
        bitret += str((b >> i) & 1)
```

For millions of bits/bytes you'll want to convert this to a streaming method instead, as you'd need a lot of memory otherwise.