# python manipulating single bits of data

Tags: python, binary-data

I am trying to open a file in binary mode so that I can manipulate it at a bit level.

I am trying to obtain the binary information with:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

but when I try to print this out I get a mixture of hex and some strange (to me) characters like the following

```
...~\xeb\xdd{\xdf\xba\xf7^\xf7\xee\xbd\xd7\...
```

how do I obtain the binary information as 0's and 1's with the ability to change 0110 1001 into 1001 0110

Comment: Why do you want to manipulate at the binary level? What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I am currently studying cryptography and would like to implement what I am learning in code

Comment: See [_How I can read a bit in Python?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689748/how-i-can-read-a-bit-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary data is just numbers. What's more, Python pretty much treats a `boolean` or a `byte` the same way as an `int`. Using `BytesIO` will let you access the file as a stream of numbers, each representing a byte.

To input a number in base 2, use the `0b00000000` syntax. To view the number in the same way, use `"{:08b}".format(number)`. And to change `0b01101001` into `0b10010110`, use `~0b01101001 & 0xFF`. The `~` operator flips the bits, while the `& 0xFF` is just a mask to zero the remaining 24 bits from the `int`. (That's necessary because since we flipped all 32 bits, all those leading 0s are now 1s, and we don't want that at all).

Comment: thanks, this has helped a lot, though if for example I want to change flip one single bit     "{:08b}".format(number)    results in a string which is not mutable. is there a different way of doing this to allow single bit manipulation?

Comment: You have to understand that the string representation is aimed at you as the user. To Python, the numbers are *always* just bits. If you want to flip a bit, use XOR (`^`). `255 ^ 1` is *exactly the same* as `0b11111111 ^ 0b00000001`, or for that matter `0xFF ^ 0x01`. It flips the last bit, and the result is `0b11111110`, or `254` or any other way you can think of to represent that number. There are plenty of other bitwise operators too.