# Why is binary file bigger?

Tags: python, binary, huffman-code

I created a compressor for my online course project using huffman algorithm. Problem is that the output file in binary (`10101010011..`) is bigger than the original files.

Teachers on the course don't know the answer.

I use this, where `ciph_text` is a string of 0s and 1s.

```
with open(full_name,'w') as temp:
    temp.write(ciph_text)
```

Any idea?
I can post more code if requested.

Comment: because you are saving as a string, so every character counts as 8 bits instead of 1

Comment: also avoid `with open(full_name,'w')` for binary, use `wb`

Comment: Don't know about huffmann algorithm, but anyway: Do you save a binary representation of a string, which is longer than the original string as ascii data in a file? I think you should save your bits in some bytes as a real binary file by `with open(full_name,'wb') as temp:`

Comment: Yes, you do need to added more code to your question—otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: @SpghttCd: It's used to do [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

Comment: D4N: Suggest you take look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10691412/355230) of mine which describes a way to do bitwise I/O—because I think you're writing the resulting "bits" as a text file composed of `0` and `1` _characters_ which each are at least 8-bits long, not as binary zeros and ones.

Comment: I have a string of 1s and 0s and I want to save it as a binary file. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 1):

int(x, 2) is your friend:

```
>>> a="00001010000101000001111000101000"
>>> for b in range(0, len(a), 8):
...   print a[b:b+8], int(a[b:b+8], 2)
... 
00001010 10
00010100 20
00011110 30
00101000 40
```